# Why does my project fails after 6 months of inactivity, even though it has a yarn.lock file?

Tags: node.js, npm, frontend, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have an node project that is deployed to heroku. After 6 months, I decided to add a new feature to it.

When I pull the code locally, and run `yarn install`, it works fine, but when I build the project, it fails due to some kind of error in the dependency.

I also notice that if I manually trigger a build in heroku (which would try to build the same code base that is published 6 months ago), it also fails with the same problem.

Its clearly an issue with a dependency, since my code hasn't changed at all.

I have `yarn.lock` file, so I don't understand what can cause a project that hasn't change all of a sudden stop working. Isn't the point of the lock to lock in all the versions of all dependencies?

Comment: Try, deleting the node_modules folder and install it again!

Comment: I cloned the codebase, there isn’t a node_modules folder to begin with

Comment: okay. Then delete the yarn.lock and try installing the packages.

Comment: Deleting the lock file, will regenerate the lock file which will cause newer dependencies being pulled in and some will become incompatible to each other. :(

Comment: Take two git clone's of the repo, and make changes to one of the repo to test what is causing this break.

Comment: The problem is that the build breaks when I do not make any changes to it.

For example, Heroku 6 months built and published the app successfully. If I simply trigger a build in Heroku with the same codebase from 6 months ago and the same code that is currently deployed, it will now fail to build. So I don't think its a local configuration problem or related to my code.

Comment: okay. Then how are you planning to figure out the issue?

Comment: @kavigun After further investigation, it seems that the reason is that my project node  requirement is set to `v12.x`. Everytime heroku does the build it takes the latest `v12.x` version of node. As it turns out, between `v12.16.1` and the latest `v12.18.4`, the build error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is digging up an old project and it no longer seems to work. Here is some insight for what cause the build problems for me:

In my `package.json`, I have this:

```json
"engines": {
   "node": "v12.x",   
   "yarn": "1.22.x"
},
```

This is ok in most cases, because you generally still want to pickup any minor updates and patches (especially security updates)

Build problems can occur over time, however, if these updates to node break some of the dependencies that used work in previous versions of node. In a perfect world, minor updates and patches should not break any dependency as these should not be **breaking changes**. But it can happen for various reasons (For example, a dependency is using an API incorrectly; later when the API is fixed, the dependency breaks)

In Summary:

Initially Heroku was pulling Node `v12.16.1` and my project worked fine. 6 months later, when doing a build, Heroku pulls in Node `12.18.4`. This is still technically correct, since I'm just asking for `v12.x`.

Somewhere between `v12.16.1` and `12.18.4`, one of my dependencies throws and error.

Solution:
In the `engines` section of `package.json` Put exact version numbers that you need.